# What is the difference between "this" and ObjectName(ex: Person)?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me the differences between the two codes below:

```js
var Person = {
  Cars: [],
  init: function(){ 
    this.Cars = [];
  } 
};
```

and

```js
var Person = {
      Cars: [],
      init: function(){ 
        Person.Cars = [];
      } 
    };
```

One is using "this" and the other using "Person".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different things that are happening here and it is important to realize the difference when trying to compare them.

```
var Container = {
  Cars: [],
  init: function() {
    this.Cars = [];
  }
};

var Shipment = {
  Cars: [],
  init: function() {
    Shipment.Cars = [];
  }
};
```

Lets start with the 2nd one (named `Shipment` so we can distinguish them better).

What we have is an object literal with a single method which when called would assign the value of the property `Cars` to an array.

What JS would do is first try to find what is `Shipment` and where it is defined. It is not defined in the current lexical scope/context so it would go one level up. And one level up until it finds it. This is why you could also access `Container` class from here via the same approach as well.

In this case it finds it since it was defined **before** the execution of the `init` function in the global scope. So we find `Shipment` and then we assign the array to it. So what we did is actually look for the object literal outside of our current scope and keep looking until we find it. If we can not JS obviously would throw an error. There is more to this when you do [use strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and `default binding` but that is maybe little bit off-topic.

**In the first case** we are asking JS to give us the owner of the method in the current lexical context. This is what in this case `this` means. Guess what ... the owner is `Container` and lucky for us we can move along with the assignment of the Cars property as per plan.

Now have in mind that depending on the execution `this` could have [very different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) `meaning` and in the case of the ES6 arrow functions it would always be the [enclosing lexical context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions). Then with the help of ECMAScript 5 and functions like [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method) you can make it what you want basically (although somewhat frown upon as practice these days). But in this specific example I think that should cover it for the most part.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, `init` will *always* create (or reassign) a `Cars` property on `Person`. On the other hand, in the first code, the object on which a `Cars` property is created depends on the calling context. For example, if you were to put the `init` function onto some other object and then called it, that other object would get mutated:

```js
var Person = {
  Cars: [],
  init: function(){ 
    this.Cars = [];
  } 
};

var myVar = {};
myVar.init = Person.init;
myVar.init();
console.log(myVar);
```

You could do the same sort of thing if you used `.call`:

```js
var Person = {
  Cars: [],
  init: function(){ 
    this.Cars = [];
  } 
};

var myVar = {};
Person.init.call(myVar);
console.log(myVar);
```

When you refer to `this`, you're referring to the calling context, rather than a static variable / object.